# Datepicker jQuery does not update ngModel AngularJS 4

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I tried to put the datepicker value to an angle variable but it did not work, if someone can help me, I am very grateful.
My code AngularJS & jQuery:

```
public inicializaDatepicker() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        showOn: "focus",
        autoSize: this.tamanioAuto,
        dateFormat: this.formato,
        changeMonth: this.mesEnCombo,
        changeYear:  this.anioEnCombo,
        yearRange: this.anioMin + ':' + this.anioMax,
        onSelect: function () {
          $(this).trigger('input');
          $(this).trigger('change');
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that ngModel does not detect any change in the input.
My HTML:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="datepicker [(ngModel)]="valor" (ngModelChange)="handleSelected()" />
```